# Changing the PATH variable on FReeBSD

Tags: maven, environment-variables, freebsd, setenv

I am trying to install Maven on FreeBSD (version 10.0-RELEASE-p7) using the following documentation

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/installation-sect-maven-install.html

I am using 'setenv' instead of 'export' to set my variables. However when I try to add maven to my path I get the following error

```
setenv: Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters.
```

This is the command I am trying to use

```
setenv PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

Anybody knows a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for the setenv command in the C shell is

```
setenv VAR "value"
```